# File inside cache

Tags: android

[image]Android cannot found file inside a cache directory, is this its nature or there's something wrong with me code? Android cannot find my file. Thanks for the help.

Okey I already figured this out. I just misplaced the file. Thanks anyway.

```
File file = new File(this.getCacheDir().toString() + "/cacheYelawolf-Daddys-Lambo.mp3");
    if(file.exists()) {
        Log.i("FILE", "file exists");
    } else {
        Log.i("FILE", "file not found");
    }
```

Comment: 1) are you sure it's there?, 2) Try `new File(getCacheDir(),"cacheYelaw.....mp3)`

Comment: try printing `file.getAbsolutePath()` verify if the path is correct.

Comment: FILE ABSOLUTEPATH(5702): /data/data/law.android.cache/cache/cacheYelawolf-Daddys-Lambo.mp3 <-- looks fine to me.

Comment: that's not the same path as the screenshot shows - move the mp3 inside the "cache" subdir

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is because, you don't have proper permission to access that mp3 file. As you can see in the screenshot , most of the permissions are just missing and instead you can see only "hyphens". You have to change its mode before you can access it.

You might also need this code,

```
file.setReadable(true);
```